# Pasta para Models Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Bom dia, diferente do `Laravel 4`, a versão `5.1` cria os `Models` diretamente na pasta `App`, queria saber se vai influenciar em algo se eu criar pastas para organizar melhor esses `Models`.

Comment: Bem você vai ter que adicionar o caminho é, por exemplo "pasta.index";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você terá que mudar o namespace das classes de modelos. Por exemplo

```
namespace App\Models;
```

Se a pasta que você criar se chamar `Models` (caso sensível) e estiver dentro de `app`. Isso ocorre porque o `composer.json` está configurado para auto-carregar as classes dentro da pasta app no modelo PSR-4.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"            
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "App\\Models\\": "app/Models/"
    }
}
```

Após a alteração, você terá que executar um `composer dumpautoload` para gerar a nova classe de `autoload`.

---

Se estiver utilizando os sistemas de autenticação nativos do Laravel, você terá que alterar o arquivo `auth.php` em `config`.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Model
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "Eloquent" authentication driver, we need to know which
| Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your users. Of course, it
| is often just the "User" model but you may use whatever you like.
|
*/

'model' => App\Models\User::class,
```

---

Se estiver utilizando JWT, você terá que alterar o `jwt.php` em `config`

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Model namespace
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Specify the full namespace to your User model.
| e.g. 'Acme\Entities\User'
|
*/

'user' => 'App\Models\User',
```

---

### Resumindo

Pessoalmente, acredito ser uma boa prática criar os modelos dentro de uma pasta específica. O Laravel oferece fácil reconfiguração de todas as dependências para tal.

Comment: Show!! Muito obrigado pela ajuda e pelas dicas Marco!